# Is there an easy and direct way to to check whether UAC is enabled/disabled in windows?

Tags: windows, powershell, devops, windows-scripting

I'm using the following command for getting the enabled status:

```
REG QUERY HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\ /v EnableLUA
```

The output of above command in case UAC is enabled is as:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
    EnableLUA    REG_DWORD    0x1
```

And the output in case UAC is disabled remains as:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
    EnableLUA    REG_DWORD    0x0
```

The difference is **0x0** and **0x1**

For checking the similar status for a service, I'm using:
`(get-service service-name).status` command.

It gives me output as a single string only as: `Stopped/Running/Disabled`

Looking for a similar approach for knowing UAC status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you mean something like this?

```
$uac = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System' -Name 'EnableLUA' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ($null -eq $uac) { 'NotConfigured' }
elseif ($uac -eq 0) { 'Disabled' }
else { 'Enabled' }
```

Comment: Thanks @Theo. This is exactly what I need, but looking if it is possible with a single command.

Comment: @kkpareek You could wrap this in a small helper function like `Get-UacStatus` if that helps. The thing is that there are three possible returns: $null, 0 or <>0, so that rules out a simple array index method..